# Linear system resolution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've got this linear system \begin{cases} x-3y+6z=0 \\  kx-3y+6z=0\end{cases} 
I must to find the basis and the size of this linear system. I have a stuck becose here are $kx$. I made it so: 
$$\begin{align} x&=3y-6z\\
 k(3y-6z)&=3y-6z\end{align}$$But I see that my method it's wrong in this case. Cos' I don't know how to solve it. Is someone who can tell to me whot can I do in this case? Or whot I must to study? I try to search on Google but I don't find anything similar.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you mean by "size" of a linear system? What do you mean by "basis" of a linear system? Usually, a basis is something that belongs to a *vector space*. What vector space do you want the basis of?

Comment: @5um I got W=(x, y, z) €R^3. I must find the basis of this vector space. So I must to solve this linear system for understanding if this sistem is linaerly indipendent. If it is I can set that S=generated R^3 and it's become a basis. After I look how many elements in the S generated for saying the dimension (size). Is this that you asked?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 6 \\
k & -3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
that easily becomes
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 6 \\
k-1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
Now there are two cases: if $k=1$, only one equation remains, namely $x=3y-6z$, so a basis is
$$
\left\{\,
\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} -6 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\,\right\}
$$
If $k\ne1$, there are two equations, $x=0$ and $y=2z$; the RREF is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
Therefore the basis is
$$
\left\{\,
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\,\right\}
$$

Comment: It doesn’t easily become
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 6 \\
k & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ but becomes
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 6 \\
k -1& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ instead.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Oh, dear! Yes! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The second equation may be written as $(k-1)(3y-6z)=0$.  Now if $k=1$ you have $x=3y-6z$, 
hence $(3,1,0)$ and $(-6,0,1)$ form a basis.
otherwise $3y-6z=0$, which implies $x=0$.  Here $(0,2,1)$ is a basis vector.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks I made it. $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & - 3 & 6 \\ k & - 3 & 6 \end {bmatrix}$$
Determinate "k". 1*(-3)-k*(-3)=-3+3k. k=1.
For k=1
{(x=3y-6z):x,y €R}
(3y,y,0),(-6z, 0,z)
S=(3,1,0),(-6,0,1) generated W. So this is the basis and dimension =2.
For k=0
-3y=-6z
{(y=2z):z €R}
(0,2z,z)
S=(0,2,1) generated W, so this is a bases and the dimension =1.